# if statement in javascript that increase the value of variable

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement that every time its executed my result variable will be increase by 2 every time

How can I do it?

```js
function computerCard(){
    let cardForComputer = pickRandomCardForComputer();
    document.getElementById('showcardComputer').src = cardForComputer+'.jpg';
    computerValueCard = warCardGame['Computercardvalue'][cardForComputer];
    if(computerValueCard<myValueCard){
        result+=2; // how to increase by 2 and show this value to the user every time the if statement  execute 
        document.getElementById('myResult').innerHTML=result;
    }else if(computerValueCard>myValueCard){
     result+=2; 
     // how to increase by 2 and show this value to the user every time the if statement  execute 
     document.getElementById('comResult').innerHTML=result;
    }
     
 }
```

```html
<img id='showcardComputer'  width="150px" height="150px" src='http://www-cdr.stanford.edu/~petrie/blank.gif'>
<img id='showcard' width="150px" height="150px" src='http://www-cdr.stanford.edu/~petrie/blank.gif'>
```

Comment: Please describe what is your problem, and maybe add also expected output and actual output.

Comment: where is `result` initialized to`0` so you can later increment it? Unless `result` is defined outside the scope of this function,it is undefined and you should see an error in the debug tools

Comment: this is my full java script code and the expected output is the score to increase by 2 every time the if statement execute

Comment: @amiro shouldn't it be ``result += 2``?

Comment: this not the problem , i just want the result variable to be increase by 2 and shown to the user

Comment: instead of increase by 2 it show me nan

Comment: Where did you create the variable `result` ? (hint : `undefined + 2 == NaN`)

Comment: Thank u but i fix the problem